# Testing if a URL requires SNI

Tags: ssl, sni

I have [a site](https://www.centralbaptistchelmsford.org) which is served over HTTPS, but which iTunes can't find. My suspicion is that it's related to the iTunes backend server being Java 6, and Java 6 not supporting SNI. SSL Labs seems to hint that my site does require SNI (see [this report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=centralbaptistchelmsford.org), and search for SNI), but I can't think why. Have I misunderstood multi-domain certificates? I've got multiple sites running on the same server, but my understanding was that as long as all the URLs were listed as Subject Alternative Names on the certificate, that all would be well.

Does anyone know a good way to check if a URL requires SNI support on the client to access it? I don't have a Windows XP/Java 6 install around to play with sadly.

Comment: Beginning to think that the SSL Labs test just includes which clients do/don't support SNI, and that they're not saying that the URL in question requires SNI - see [this report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=74.125.224.16&hideResults=on) for an IP address mapped to by google.com.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/506177/how-can-i-detect-if-a-server-is-using-sni-for-https/780388#780388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx in general, and your site in particular, accepts but doesn't require SNI. To test this you cannot easily use **Oracle Java** out of the box, because its `cacerts` **does not include** `DST Root CA X3` which is **the root cert used** (initially) by 'Let's Encrypt' who issued your site's cert; this is true for all versions of Oracle Java up to current (8u74). Windows (hence IE and Chrome on Windows) and Firefox do have this root cert; I can't say for other OS or browsers.

To fix this so you can easily test, either:

- use Oracle Java 6 but modify `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` to add the DSTX3 cert, obtained either from your OS or browser, or by following the link at https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ to https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html -- except that page nonstandardly gives you only the base64 body of the cert so you must manually add the PEM header and trailer lines before Java `keytool` will import it.
- use Oracle Java 6 as-is but configure your application (with system properties) to use a custom truststore which you create containing the DSTX3 cert as above.
- use a version of Java 6 that does include this root cert in cacerts. In particular I use CentOS 6 and its openjdk packages (for 6, 7, and 8) use a systemwide CA 'bundle' that includes DSTX3, which is what made it easy for me to do this test. I expect, but can't confirm, that other RedHat variants do the same. For other distros and platforms I can't say; if not, see above.

Monitor the connection attempt with wireshark or similar to see that the ClientHello does not contain SNI, but the connection succeeds and is successfully used for an HTTP request.

If you actually want to communicate with the server instead of testing it for SNI, simply omit the final 'monitor' step.

Answer (score 7):

The reports from SSLLabs regarding SNI are usually correct. Your understanding that SNI is not needed if your certificate contains all possible hosts is correct too. But, not needed in theory does not mean that your server setup does not require SNI anyway.

> I don't have a Windows XP/Java 6 install around to play with sadly.

Given that you only specify what you don't have I will assume that you have everything else which might be used. A simple way to check is openssl:

```
 # without SNI
 $ openssl s_client -connect host:port 

 # use SNI
 $ openssl s_client -connect host:port -servername host
```

Compare the output of both calls of `openssl s_client`. If they differ in the certificate they serve or if the call w/o SNI fails to establish an SSL connection than you need SNI to get the correct certificate or to establish a SSL connection at all.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to check if a site relies on SNI is this:

```
openssl s_client -servername alice.sni.velox.ch -tlsextdebug -msg \
    -connect alice.sni.velox.ch:443 2>/dev/null | grep "server name"
```

And if in that output you see the following, it means the site is using SNI.

> TLS server extension "server name" (id=0), len=0

The above is a summary of [an answer at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/506177/how-can-i-detect-if-a-server-is-using-sni-for-https/780388#780388).

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. I think this only shows you if the site *supports* SNI, not requires it.  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ will flag "This site works only in browsers with SNI support." if a site requires SNI though.